# How to place a value in a dropdown if the database has a null field C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a repeater that builds a dropdown menu.  There is a field that places the URL in the value attribute.  The field is nullable in the database, so for items that do not have a URL the value is empty.  I need to replace that with something even if it is just '#' so that the validation works.

**Mark-Up**

```
<ItemTemplate>
        <option data-siteid="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SiteID") %>" value="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "URL") %>">
            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %>
        </option>
</ItemTemplate>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
private void BindMakeList()
    {
        var makeList = this.repository.GetMakes();

        rptDropDown.DataSource = makeList;
        rptDropDown.DataBind();

    }
```

Comment: what does `GetMakes()` return? im assuming something that has SiteID, URL and Name. Im thinking you can just loop through that variable and just replace any empty URL with #

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
value="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "URL") ?? "#" %>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using String.IsNullOrEmpty in Value field

```
<%# String.IsNullOrEmpty(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SiteID")) ? "#": DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SiteID")  %>
```

Comment: This is just a longer way of writing the same code as mines. The [null coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) was designed to avoid this type of code.